# Git commit registered in log but not showing up in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-log

It seems my github account is skipping a commit I made for some reason.

[image: I'm trying to re-commit the "Improved comments in HTML and JS]

I am trying to re-commit the "Improved comments in HTML and JS log selection in the attached image.

I think things got messed up because I made these comment changes, committed but didn't push, then edited the README in the browser and didn't pull. Then I attempted a push and got a record issue and a merge issue.

Can anyone confirm or deny whether this is what is causing my issue?

Can anyone help me get this commit registered on Github somehow?

Thank you so much!

Comment: ... did you do a `git push`?

Comment: Most likely doing `git pull origin yourBranch` followed by `git push origin yourBranch` will resolve this.  This assumes that you have committed the work in question.  Also, there may be merge conflicts when you pull; you'll have to resolve those.

Comment: Try `push origin HEAD:master` or `git reset HEAD~1` and then add -> commit -> push again

Comment: Unlike SVN's commit, Git's commit is a local action.